# Passing linked list node to pthread function correctly

Tags: c, pthreads, linked-list

Please see my pseudo-code below.  The code comments should explain my problem.  I'm new to both pthreads and linked lists in C so I've jumped into the deep end a bit.  I just need to print the value of `str` out in the `thread_work` function.  The sequential bit of code is fine but when each thread does its work, it can't print out the value of `str`.

```
// linked list definition
struct linked_list {
   char *str;
   struct linked_list *next;
};

// linked list initiation
struct linked_list *root;
struct linked_list *next_info;
root = malloc( sizeof( struct linked_list ) );

// main code
some loop {
   next_node->str = str;
   printf( "%s\n", next_node ); // PRINTS FINE
   pthread_t thread;
   rc = pthread_create( &thread, NULL, thread_work, (void *) &next_node );
   next_node->next = malloc( sizeof( struct linked_list ) );
   next_node = next_node->next;
}

// code executed by each thread
void *thread_work( void *thread_arg ) {
   struct linked_list *ll;
   ll = ( struct linked_list * )thread_arg;
   printf( "%s\n", ll->str ); // PRINTS SOME MESS (��E#)
}
```

In my actual code there are a few more members of the `linked_list` `struct`.

Many thanks.

Comment: Just a note: since `thread_arg` is `void *`, there's absolutely no need to cast when converting to another data pointer type. Just do it: `struct linked_list *ll = thread_arg;"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a pointer type mismatch: you are passing a pointer to a pointer to list node, but inside  `thread_work` you treat it as a pointer to node. Either remove the ampersand before `next_node` in the call to `pthread_create`, or change your `thread_work` as follows:

```
void *thread_work( void *thread_arg ) {
    struct linked_list **llp, *ll;
    llp = ( struct linked_list ** )thread_arg;
    ll = *llp;
    printf( "%s\n", ll->str ); // PRINTS SOME GOOD STUFF
}
```

Comment: THANK YOU.  I'll mark this as solved then the minimum time has expired.

Answer (score 0):

if `printf( "%s\n", next_node )` works fine, *next_node* is a pointer and therefor you schouldn't point to the pointer in *pthread_create()*.
Definition of *next_node* would be nice ;)

try `rc = pthread_create( &thread, NULL, thread_work, (void *) next_node );`

Answer (score 0):

This code is bad:

```
// main code
some loop {
  next_node->str = str;
  printf( "%s\n", next_node ); // PRINTS FINE
  pthread_t thread;
  rc = pthread_create( &thread, NULL, thread_work, (void *) &next_node );
  next_node->next = malloc( sizeof( struct linked_list ) );
  next_node = next_node->next;
}
```

The problem here is that you are passing a pointer to a variable whose value changes immediately after the call to `pthread_create`. As it takes some time for the OS to clone the process into a new thread, the actual `thread_work` might (and in most cases will) start after the `next_node = next_node->next;` statement was executed and pick the wrong value of `next_node`. You should pass the value of `next_node`, not its address:

```
// main code
some loop {
  next_node->str = str;
  printf( "%s\n", next_node->str ); // PRINTS FINE
  pthread_t thread;
  rc = pthread_create( &thread, NULL, thread_work, (void *) next_node );
  // Store this thread handle somewhere safe to be able to join the thread later on
  next_node->next = malloc( sizeof( struct linked_list ) );
  next_node->next->str = next_node->next->next = NULL; // Always a good idea
  next_node = next_node->next;
}
```